# Rails validation: implicity presence validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Let's say in my form there is a phone field, which has a format validation:

```
validates_length_of :phone, :is => 9
```

However, this is not a requiered field. It can be blank, but **if** filled in, then the format validation should start working.

How can I "disable" the implicit presence validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `allow_blank` to skip validation if the field isn't set:

```
validates :phone, :length => { :is => 9 }, :allow_blank => true
```

See [the Rails validations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank) for additional details.

So, for your explicit example:

```
validates_length_of :phone, :is => 9, :allow_blank => true
```

Will allow the `phone` field to be an empty string or nil, and skip the validation.